# Accessing a bool from a different script in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bool variable (`isGrounded`) from my player's movement control script that I want to access in another `GameObject`.

BallController.cs

```
public class BallController : MonoBehaviour {
    Transform myTrans;
    Rigidbody2D myBody;

    public bool isGrounded = true;
    public bool release = false;
}
```

GravityPull.cs

```
public class GravityPull : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject target;
    public int moveSpeed;
    public int maxdistance;
    private float distance;


    void Start ()
    {
        target= (GameObject.Find("Ball (1)"));
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        distance = Vector2.Distance (target.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distance < maxdistance && target.isGrounded)
        {
             target.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(target.transform.position, transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime / distance);
        }
    }
}
```

If I make my target a `GameObject` than I can find it using `.find`. But if I do this I can't access the bool. If I make my target a `BallController` then I can access the bool, but I can't use `.find` to find the class. I also can't cast the `GameObject` as a `BallController`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your target suppose to be a BallControler ? You could simply call GetComponent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
target.getComponent<BallController>().isGrounded
```

this should be sufficient.